# Recebendo uma requisição ajax com laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5, laravel-5.2

Estou tendo problemas em recuperar os dados enviados pelo meu ajax para o `laravel`.

Meu `ajax` está assim:

```
var id = $(this).siblings(':hidden').val(),
    qtd = $(this).val(),
    dataUser = { "id": id, "qtd": qtd};

 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'rel':dataUser},
    url: window.location.href + "/atualiza",
    success: function (e) {
           alert(e);
    }
 });
```

E em meu `controller` está assim:

```
public function atualizaQtd(){
    $arr = json_decode($_POST['rel'], true);
    return $arr;
}
```

E assim a minha rota:

```
Route::post('/carrinho/atualiza', [
   'uses' => 'CartController@atualizaQtd',
   'as' => 'carrinho.atualiza'
]);
```

Preciso acessar os dados de `id` e `qtd` la em meu `controller` para efetuar uma atividade.

Como faço isto ? Tentei receber com utilização do método `Requests` e também não consegui.

> Ao fazer não da nenhum erro, apenas não retorna nada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem ajuste a serem feitos para envio [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) no [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)**:**

Dentro da ***tag*** `head` do `html` precisa ter:

> `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
    <script src="/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head>
```

porque, requisição com `verb` **`POST`** tem a proteção [**`CSRF Protection`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token) ativa por padrão. Na parte do [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) precisa de um ajuste que é a adição de um `header` no `$.ajaxSetup`: **`X-CSRF-TOKEN`**.

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    function send(){
        var id  = $(this).siblings(':hidden').val();
        var qtd = $(this).val();
        var dataUser = { "id": id, "qtd": qtd};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'rel':dataUser},
            url: '{{route("carrinho.atualiza")}}',
            success: function (e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

observe que também teve no `$.ajax` modificado a `url`, colocando `route` e chamando a rota que foi criada no arquivo de rotas do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel). Foi criado isso tudo dentro de uma `function` de nome `send()`.

No `controller` pode e deve utilizar [**`Request`**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests):

```
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function atualizaQtd(Request $request)
    {
        $rel = $request->get('rel');
        $id  = $rel['id'];
        $qtd = $rel['qtd'];
        return $id.'-'.$qtd;
    }
}
```

com esses ajustes e observações funcionará a requisição [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) e os valores estarão disponíveis.

Comment: Nao esta pegando a requisição tenho que colocar a função aonde ?

Comment: Vale lembrar que o que movia isto é o evento de alteração de um campo a qtd, a ideia é que sempre que mude a quantidade ele va ao banco e altera

Comment: @RenanRodrigues para alterar ele precisa ser chamada, não tem essa informação na sua pergunta!

Comment: @RenanRodrigues na sua pergunta você não colocou também o que está fazendo, a resposta já é uma solução sobre o que postou!!!